# Object is rewritten unexpectedly

Tags: php

I've been toying around with this silly problem for about an hour now. Thinking I just lost my brain from working so late.

Here's a bit of code:

```
       foreach ( ..) {

            if ($offer->device_code == 15) {

                $offer->device_code = 2;
                $offer_array[] = $offer;

                $offer->device_code = 1;
                $offer_array[] = $offer;

            } else {

            $offer_array[] = $offer;

            }
        }

        $this->offer_array = $offer_array;
        return true
```

In my mind, I expect every $offer where device_code == 15 to be duplicated inside the conditional statement. So I would that offer twice inside $offer_array, once where it's device_code = 1 and another where it's device_code = 2.

However,

```
$offer->device_code = 1;
```

Overwrites

```
$offer->device_code = 2;
```

Whichever gets thrown in $offer_array first is overwritten.

Could someone explain why this is so? And what's a better way to approach the problem?

Many thanks.

Comment: try to use `clone $offer` so you create a copy instead of the actual object.

Comment: Try to replace your "magic" numbers with constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP assigns objects *by reference*, not by value. When you are iterating your loop with the object `$offer` and you modify it to set its `device_code`, append it to the array then modify it again and append it again, you are actually appending two references to *the same object* onto your array. When you change a property of one of them, you change the property of both of them even though one appears to have been appended to an array already.

If you want to end up with two copies of the `$offer` object which are distinct, you will need to `clone` it.

```
if ($offer->device_code == 15) {

    $offer->device_code = 2;
    $offer_array[] = $offer;

    // Clone the object to an entirely new one
    $cloned = clone $offer;
    // and set its property then append to the array
    $cloned->device_code = 1;
    $offer_array[] = $cloned;

} else {

    $offer_array[] = $offer;

}
```

- [More PHP documentation about objects and references...](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php)
- [The `clone` keyword and object cloning...](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)

#### A quick example:

```
// Make an object
$s = new stdClass;
// and an array
$a = [];
// Set some properties
$s->one = 1;
$s->two = 2;
// Stick it onto the array
$a[] = $s;
// Change a property and stick another onto the array
$s->two = 3;
$a[] = $s;
print_r($a);
// Oops, both of them have the new value $s->two = 3
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [one] => 1
            [two] => 3 <--- no longer 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [one] => 1
            [two] => 3
        )

)

// Clone one and change its property
$cloned = clone $s;
$cloned->two = 4;
$a[] = $cloned;
print_r($a);

// The clone retains its own property
// since it points to an entirely different object in memory
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [one] => 1
            [two] => 3
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [one] => 1
            [two] => 3
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [one] => 1
            [two] => 4 <-- doesn't affect the other references
        )

)
```

Comment: Many thanks - I was entirely confused. I think this may also be why my process was using so much memory.

Comment: @nkconnor If you have a memory issue that may be something else. Adding additional references to the same object wouldn't appreciably affect memory.  Cloning lots and lots of copies could though - but here the `$cloned` variable is overwitten each time so you aren't building a large memory footprint of objects.

Comment: The memory issue was when I did something like this: $second_offer = $offer; then dropped both into the array. I have no memory issue now that I've implemented your suggestion, but thinking it was merely due to my puny server (70Mb of memory)